# How to send web scraped information to discord webhook with Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, discord, discord.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json

source = requests.get('http://www.jimmyjazz.com/mens/footwear/adidas-superstar/S82215?color=Brown').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
page = soup.find('div', class_='box_wrapper')
size = page.find_all('a')

for pid in size:
    if "piunavailable" not in pid["class"]:   
        print("instock")
        print("http://www.jimmyjazz.com/mens/footwear/adidas-superstar/S82215?color=Brown")
    else:
        print("out of stock")
```

This is currently what I have, I have tried sending the information that it has scraped a few different ways but have had no success in sending it to my discord webhook. I would love any help at all, thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to post information to your hook through Python?

Comment: yes, all that code I have written there returns the shoe sizes in stock and out of stock, which I want to send to my discord webhook via Python

Answer (score 1):

You can use request's post method to post the formatted string to your hook. I have experience with Discord but have not set a Hook before. If the keyword for the post `params` doesn't work use `headers`. Tailor this code to your project and let me know if you have any questions or other bugs with request.

```
import json

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

payload = {'username': 'myname',
           'icon_url': 'myavatar.png'}

SHOE_URI = 'http://www.jimmyjazz.com/mens/footwear/adidas-superstar/S82215?color=Brown'
DISCORD_HOOK_URI = 'https://discordapp.com/whateverapi'

source = requests.get(SHOE_URI).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
page = soup.find('div', class_='box_wrapper')
sizes = page.find_all('a')

avail = dict() # keeps track of the status for each size

for pid in sizes:
    if "piunavailable" in pid["class"]:   
        avail[pid.getText()] = "out of stock"
    else:
        avail[pid.getText()] = "instock"

maxlen = max(map(len, avail.keys())) # for right-justified string formatting
string = '\n'.join("{:>{}}: {}".format(size, maxlen, value) for size, value in avail.items())

myheaders['content'] = string

req = requests.post(DISCORD_HOOK_URI, params=payload)
if req.status_code != 200:
   print('post failed with error', req.status_code, 'because', req.reason)
else:
   print('post success')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll give this a shot!